# Searching by object property with UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, uisearchcontroller

In my `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method, I have a searchPredicate that I use to find matches, however, I want to learn how to use it with an Object's property.

I have an object called `Product` that has a String property called `title` which I would like to use as my search parameter. So far, this is what my search function looks like:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        productSearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

        let array = (orderGuideItemsList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        productSearchResults = array as! [Product]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

where `orderGuideItemsList` is an array of `Product` objects

So is there a way for me to search based on `Proudct`'s `title` property? It doesn't have to use a predicate but that's what I have from a previous tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your predicate to

`let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.title CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)`

This should work fine.